# PHP foreach not working with sub-array

Tags: php, mongodb, foreach, arrays

I need to work out how to do I get the following to work.

I have an array with sub-array

```
array (
  'session' => '1359964785.85203874781',
  'status' => 'cart',
  'items' => 
  array (
    'id' => '510bca8138fc5d6e38000000',
    'quantity' => '1',
  ),
)
```

then when I put that array thought my foreach

```
<?php
       $cart = Shop::get_cart();
       ;
            if($cart != NULL)
            { 
                foreach($cart[0]['items'] as $items)
                {
                    print $items['id'];
                ?>
                <tr>

                </tr>
                <?php
                }   
            }
       ?>
```

I can't seem to access the sub array for items. What I want to be able to do is call it like

```
$items["id"];
$items["quantity"];
```

**EDIT**

I am getting the data from MongoDB by the following code

```
public function get_cart()
    {
        $collection = static::db()->redi_shop_orders;
        $cursor = $collection->find(array('session' => $_SESSION["redi-Shop"]));
        if ($cursor->count() > 0)
        {
            $posts = array();
            // iterate through the results
            while( $cursor->hasNext() ) {   
                $posts[] = ($cursor->getNext());
            }
            return $posts;
        }
    }
```

which when I do a print out returns

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [_id] => MongoId Object ( [$id] => 510f8eba38fc5d7d43000000 ) [session] => 1359964785.85203874781 [status] => cart [items] => Array ( [id] => 510bca8138fc5d6e38000000 [quantity] => 1 ) ) )
```

Comment: `is_array($cart)`? `isset($cart[0])`? `isset($cart[0]['items'])`?  `is_array($cart[0]['items'])`? - There's some really basic debugging you can do on your own.

Answer (score 4):

YOu should replace

```
foreach($cart[0]['items'] as $items)
```

with

```
foreach($cart['items'] as $items)
```

Comment: foreach($cart['items'] as $items)

Comment: `var_dump($cart)` what do you have ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   $cart = array (
  'session' => '1359964785.85203874781',
  'status' => 'cart',
  'items' => 
  array (
 'id' => '510bca8138fc5d6e38000000',
'quantity' => '1',
 ),
);

        if($cart != NULL)
        { 
            foreach($cart['items'] as $items)
            {
                print $items['id'];
            ?>
            <tr>

            </tr>
            <?php
            }   
        }
   ?>
```

Comment: Could you explain what went wrong and how you fixed it? That way it will be clear very fast to everyone.